# Problema com línguas no laravel

Tags: laravel, route

Tenho um sistema de línguas em laravel, estou a usar o sistema deles o localization.
Tenho o sistema a funcionar, o que acontece e que quando volto para o domínio.com da erro eu queria que ai mostra-se por padrão uma língua a definir por mim é possível ?

**Route**

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'{lang}'], function (){
   Route::get('/', function ($lang) {
      App::setLocale($lang);
      return view('home');
   });
   Route::get('/login', function ($lang) {
      App::setLocale($lang);
      return view('login');
   });
   Route::get('/registo', function ($lang) {
      App::setLocale($lang);
      return view('registo');
   });
   Route::get('/termos', function ($lang) {
      App::setLocale($lang);
      return view('termos');
   });
   Route::get('/sobre', function ($lang) {
      App::setLocale($lang);
      return view('sobre');
   });
   Route::get('/contactos', function ($lang) {
      App::setLocale($lang);
      return view('contactos');
   });
});
```

**Erro**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: se você fizer domínio.com ele dá o erro, porque não passou o lang como prefixo ?

Comment: e da esse se eu fizer domínio.com, como resolvo ?

Comment: então, se deveria guardar essa lang em algum session ou cookie para esse caso em especifico. e testar a entrada `Route::get('/', function ($lang) {
     if (!empy($lang))  App::setLocale($lang);
      return view('home');
   });`

Comment: Desculpa apesar que a sua rota padrão tem um prefix esse é o problema